# How to combine soql in apex

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I want to write a sql like this:

```
SELECT Category_ID__c, Name FROM VirtualCaseCases__c WHERE Category_ID__c  = (SELECT  Category_ID__c FROM VirtualCaseCategory__c  ORDER BY Category_ID__c ASC LIMIT 1)
```

but there is Unknown error parsing query error, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Its not totally clear from your question exactly what your trying to filter. But if you want to get a list of parents that have a child record try something like this:

```
select name from parent where 
      id in (select parentId from child)
```

Also you haven't used `IN` in `WHERE` clause as it might return multiple records.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT Category_ID__c, Name FROM VirtualCaseCases__c WHERE Category_ID__c  IN (SELECT  Category_ID__c FROM VirtualCaseCategory__c  ORDER BY Category_ID__c ASC LIMIT 1)
```